# how do I bend this mesh with weight paint mode or animation mode

Tags: rigging

My pants won't fold properly. It folds strangely. I tried weight paint, but it looked impossible. Is this the part that should be dealt with in animation?
I'd like to bend this part using rigging. an you make this part natural in animation mode?

[image]

[my file](https://cafeattach.naver.net/f267ee5a467978cee9036755698bf188287a84e1/20200702_109_cafefile/30035139_1593652235209_G9Qy1l_blend/hime%20hina5.blend?type=attachment)
[my file2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bm5dIu2xdexd4TpokqE-asiDZTTPFyxn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: *I tried weight paint, but it looked impossible.* - This is exactly what weight painting is for. Rigging is a difficult craft, which needs to be learned and practiced.

Comment: Ok. I will make a title more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a weight paint issue. Take your time, examine all the bones and the weights associated with them. It will be difficult to understand the concept the first time, but keep doing it and you will definitely find it easier over time.

Parenting with auto weights only works well, if your bones structure is good.

Comment: awoo. thank you. but it is hard.